# How to add full curl effect in Modal Segue's transition?

Tags: segue, xcode-storyboard

I want curly effects like iBook pages.

How to do it using Segue with storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

you should make use of the UIPageViewController.

This allows you exactly to utilize the iBook-like curl effects, however IMHO it has to be done programmatically.

You could use this tutorial for a good start:

http://www.ioslearner.com/implementing-uipageviewcontroller-programatically-without-storyboarding/